# Creating a raw printer queue in CUPS (host) and adding them through CUPS (client)

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I want to make my RasPi act as a little print and file server in a small home network consisting of three Linux clients. Unfortunately, Brother provides only binary drivers for x86, so I cannot run my Brother printer on the RasPi. However, I found a blog entry proposing to create a raw queue on the RasPi's CUPS install and access this queue from the clients using binary drivers installed on them. Here is the blog entry: http://chemdroid.net/en/raspberry-pi/36-raspberry-pi-as-print-server

Unfortunately, the author doesn't describe in much details how to create a raw queue on the RasPi and how to access it from the clients, instead he concentrates on describing the installation of a non-standard CUPS version on the RasPi.

I found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271871/cups-bypassing-interface However, I don't fully understand the answer. Does the "How to setup CUPS 'raw' queues" section in the answer there refer to the host (the RasPi)? If so, what is the socket/port that I have to specify? The printer is a Brother HL-2030, connected through USB.

When accessing the printer from the clients, the answer says how to edit the 'lp' command, however I want to use the shared printer through CUPS, so how do I proceed here?

Thanks for any input!

Photon

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old post, but some people may have this doubt today.

Try to add the printer to cups using native cups "Brother DCP-7030 using brlaser v3" (or v4, depends on cups version)

Comment: In the mean time I found out how to make Brother printers work with no drivers on the Raspi and official binary drivers on the clients: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-set-up-a-remote-printer-which-is-attached-to-a-raspberry-pi-or-any-other-arm-computer/57056

Comment: Uhm, this can be useful for me in the future, since new versions of cups servers not support raw queues anymore, and I use it a lot in my organization.

Comment: Actually, Brother released ARM drivers in the mean time. Printing is quite slow on my first gen Raspberry Pi using them but it works.